# Can't select a field by using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing a test on a webpage by using c# and selenium.
The problem is that i've got 3 different select field.
Attached a photo.
[image]

The first one is always enabled, the second one is disabled until in the firstone a voice is selected, the same fo the 3rd one, that becomes selectable when in the second one a voice has been selected.

[image]

The code that i use to fill the fields is that one:

```
SelectElement selAppl = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("IdApplicazione")));
selAppl.SelectByValue(dataApp.ToString());

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(driver.FindElement((By.Id("IdDDLAmbito")))));
SelectElement selAmbito = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("IdDDLAmbito")));
selAmbito.SelectByValue(ambito);
        
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(driver.FindElement((By.Id("ddlFunzionalita")))));
SelectElement selFunzionalita = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlFunzionalita")));
selFunzionalità.SelectByValue(funzionalita);
```

The problem is that the first two fields are selected correctly, but the 3rd desn't select nothing and the test fails with that message:

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

If i put a Thread sleep instead of:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(driver.FindElement((By.Id("ddlFunzionalita")))));
SelectElement selFunzionalità = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlFunzionalita")));
```

it works. The error is reported on the code line that corrispond the:

```
SelectElement selFunzionalità = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlFunzionalita")));
```

So what i'm asking to myself, i've catched the dom variation of that element with the condition before, why does it doesn't find it?
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Including a screenshot of the page is good, but please also include a representative example of the HTML as plain text as well.

Comment: Just for fun, trying waiting for stale for ddlFunzionalita twice. I'm wondering if it doesn't reload for SELECT1 then again for SELECT2... or something... hard to tell without seeing the page.

Answer (score -1):

If you get 'StaleElementReferenceException' it means that the element was changed becase the DOM changed.
You need to to find that 3rd element again after clicking on the 1st and seconds element.

After you click on dropdowns (or other elements), the web page may changed. Other divs or span are added to the page or attributes of the same element you already found.

Comment: If you read, in the instruction:

SelectElement selFunzionalità = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlFunzionalita")));

i search again that element with findelement. It's right or i'm assuming wrong?

Comment: @AlessioOrlando It may be that the element appears with the same ID, but this in not the same element you had before. After clicking on the dropdowns, the page is being refreshed with new elements.

Comment: If you look at the code he posted, he DOES use find element again after the stale check. He's already doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: I am correct. When a dropdown is selected - it's like a totally new page. Think about it like this: each dropdown opens a new page. It's element with same attributes (or ID), but it a completely different one from the one you had before

Comment: @TalAngel really thank you for your interest. I've understood what you say, but i think that once i cathced the stale of that element, tahat one doesn't exist anymore or at least as changed. Then, i do a findelement for id, so if a new one has replaced the first, i should find the new one with that instruction. Does it makes sense?

Comment: @AlessioOrlando Yes. You think it is the same one because it has the same Id, but the old one died. So you need to check for the new element in the page with this Id.